# Some results in my joined table are NULL why is that?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query to search for companies. Each company has some properties which are stored in another table.

The value that is posted to my query and that people search with is called `tags`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT cnt.id as content_id, cnt.title as content_title, cnt.featured, cnt.ordering, cnt.alias as content_alias, cnt.catid, cnt.images, cnt.state, cnt.introtext,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 7 then f.value end) as hoofdafbeelding,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 8 then f.value end) as openingstijden,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 9 then f.value end) as straat,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 10 then f.value end) as facebook,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 11 then f.value end) as instagram,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 12 then f.value end) as telefoonnummer,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 13 then f.value end) as website,
MAX(case when f.field_id = 16 then f.value end) as tags
FROM snm_content cnt
LEFT JOIN snm_fields_values f
ON cnt.id = f.item_id
WHERE f.value LIKE '%vlees%'
GROUP BY cnt.id, cnt.title, cnt.featured, cnt.alias, cnt.catid, cnt.images, cnt.state, cnt.introtext
ORDER BY cnt.ordering
```

My problem is in my result all fields (the lines with MAX) are NULL except for tags. Why is that?

Above query gives me this result:

[image]

All NULL fields are stores exactly the same way as `tags` but `tags` shows its value while the others are NULL, why?

Also all fields are no column names, they are aliases since they all are stored as `value` which is connected with the `field_id`

I need all data to be retrieved and only search (`LIKE %%`) within `tags`.

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text... Formatted text, not images, please.

Comment: @twan do you expect hoofdafbeelding, openingstijden, straat.. all calculated fields contain 'vlees'?

Comment: @ZekiGumus No only `tags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said only tags should contain 'vlees' value. So, you shouldn't put it to WHERE because it filter whole query instead of only tags. I have updated your query, changed the place of 'vlees' filter. If the other fields (hoofdafbeelding,openingstijden..) should have another filter you should filter them like tags which I updated.
One last thing, I think the f.field_id=? filter is not correct as well. With this filter your result CASE will work only for one content.id, probably you should remove them.

```
SELECT
    cnt.id AS content_id
   ,cnt.title AS content_title
   ,cnt.featured
   ,cnt.ordering
   ,cnt.alias AS content_alias
   ,cnt.catid
   ,cnt.images
   ,cnt.state
   ,cnt.introtext
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 7   THEN f.value END) AS hoofdafbeelding
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 8   THEN f.value END) AS openingstijden
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 9   THEN f.value END) AS straat
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 10  THEN f.value END) AS facebook
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 11  THEN f.value END) AS instagram
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 12  THEN f.value END) AS telefoonnummer
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 13  THEN f.value END) AS website
   ,MAX(CASE WHEN f.field_id = 16  THEN f.value END) AS tags
FROM snm_content cnt
LEFT JOIN snm_fields_values f ON cnt.id = f.item_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM snm_fields_values SFV WHERE cnt.id = SFV.item_id AND  SFV.value LIKE '%vlees%')
GROUP BY cnt.id
        ,cnt.title
        ,cnt.featured
        ,cnt.alias
        ,cnt.catid
        ,cnt.images
        ,cnt.state
        ,cnt.introtext
ORDER BY cnt.ordering
```

Comment: Above query gives me all companies with all data so that is good except it also shows companies whose tags are NULL/EMPTY. I only want to see the companies that have `vlees` in their tags

Comment: @vlees I just understood what you need. I have updated my query with using EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering on the second column in a `left join`.  This is suspicious.  The normal advice is to move this to an `on` clause:

```
FROM snm_content cnt LEFT JOIN
     snm_fields_values f
     ON cnt.id = f.item_id AND f.value LIKE '%vlees%'
```

On the other hand, in this case, I think you might not want that condition at all in the query.

If you actually want to search through the tags, then you can use:

```
having tags like '%vlees%'
```

Comment: If I use having instead of where (your above code) I get this error: `There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY cnt.id, cnt.title, cnt.featured, cnt.alias, cnt.catid, cnt.images, cnt.' at line 12]`

Comment: @twan . . . `HAVING` follows the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

**Your case statements needs to include an else clauses. Also your left outer join could be returning null records**.

```
SELECT cnt.id as content_id, cnt.title as content_title, ...
   MAX(case when f.field_id = 7 then f.value else isnull({Column Name}, {Column Name}) end) as hoofdafbeelding,
   MAX(case when f.field_id = 8 then f.value else isnull({Column Name}, {Column Name}) end) as openingstijden,
   MAX(case when f.field_id = 9 then f.value else isnull({Column Name}, {Column Name}) end) as straat,
   MAX(case when f.field_id = 10 then f.value else isnull({Column Name}, {Column Name}) end) as facebook,
   MAX(case when f.field_id = 11 then f.value else isnull({Column Name}, {Column Name}) end) as instagram,
   MAX(case when f.field_id = 12 then f.value else isnull({Column Name}, {Column Name}) end) as telefoonnummer,
   MAX(case when f.field_id = 13 then f.value else isnull({Column Name}, {Column Name}) end) as website,
   MAX(case when f.field_id = 16 then f.value else isnull({Column Name}, {Column Name}) end) as tags
```